# How to estimate whether the objective expression has a global minimum value?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, inequalities

I have an expression concerning $x$ as follows (from my friend).

$f(x)=x^4-2 a d x^3-2 b d x^3-2 c d x^3-2 d x^3+a^2 d^2 x^2+b^2 d^2 x^2+c^2 d^2 x^2+4 a d^2 x^2+2 a b d^2 x^2+3 b d^2 x^2+2 a c d^2 x^2+3 b c d^2 x^2+3 c d^2 x^2-a b x^2-a c x^2-b c x^2+2 a b d x^2+2 a c d x^2+2 b c d x^2+2 d x^2-x^2-2 a^2 d^3 x-b^2 d^3 x-b c^2 d^3 x-c^2 d^3 x-3 a b d^3 x-b^2 c d^3 x-3 a c d^3 x-2 a b c d^3 x-2 b c d^3 x-2 a b^2 d^2 x-2 a c^2 d^2 x-2 b c^2 d^2 x-4 a d^2 x-2 a^2 b d^2 x-2 a b d^2 x-2 b d^2 x-2 a^2 c d^2 x-2 b^2 c d^2 x-2 a c d^2 x-4 a b c d^2 x-4 b c d^2 x-2 c d^2 x+a b^2 d x+a c^2 d x+b c^2 d x+2 a d x+a^2 b d x+a b d x+b d x+a^2 c d x+b^2 c d x+a c d x+2 a b c d x+2 b c d x+c d x+2 a^2 d^3+2 a b^2 d^3+2 b^2 c^2 d^3+2 a c^2 d^3+2 a b c^2 d^3+2 b c^2 d^3+2 a^2 b d^3+2 a b d^3+2 a^2 c d^3+2 a b^2 c d^3+2 b^2 c d^3+2 a c d^3+8 a b c d^3-a^2 d^2-a b^2 d^2-b^2 c^2 d^2-a c^2 d^2-a b c^2 d^2-b c^2 d^2-a^2 b d^2-a b d^2-a^2 c d^2-a b^2 c d^2-b^2 c d^2-a c d^2+4 a^2 b c d^2-12 a b c d^2+4 b c d^2+a^2 b c-2 a b c+b c-4 a^2 b c d+8 a b c d-4 b c d$

where $a\geqslant b+1, b\geqslant c,  b\geqslant1, c\geqslant0, 0\leqslant d \leqslant1$ and $a,b,c$ are integers.

We would like to prove that $f(x)>0$ or $\min f(x)>0$ when
$$x\geqslant \frac{1}{2}\left(d(2a+b+c)+\sqrt{d^2(2a+b+c)^2+8a(b+c)(1-2d)}\right),$$

```
f=(-a^2)*d^2 + 2*a^2*d^3 - a*d^2*b - a^2*d^2*b + 2*a*d^3*b + 2*a^2*d^3*b - a*d^2*b^2 + 2*a*d^3*b^2 - a*d^2*c - 
  a^2*d^2*c + 2*a*d^3*c + 2*a^2*d^3*c + b*c - 2*a*b*c + a^2*b*c - 4*d*b*c + 8*a*d*b*c - 4*a^2*d*b*c + 
  4*d^2*b*c - 12*a*d^2*b*c + 4*a^2*d^2*b*c + 8*a*d^3*b*c - d^2*b^2*c - a*d^2*b^2*c + 2*d^3*b^2*c + 
  2*a*d^3*b^2*c - a*d^2*c^2 + 2*a*d^3*c^2 - d^2*b*c^2 - a*d^2*b*c^2 + 2*d^3*b*c^2 + 2*a*d^3*b*c^2 - 
  d^2*b^2*c^2 + 2*d^3*b^2*c^2 + 2*a*d*x - 4*a*d^2*x - 2*a^2*d^3*x + d*b*x + a*d*b*x + a^2*d*b*x - 2*d^2*b*x - 
  2*a*d^2*b*x - 2*a^2*d^2*b*x - 3*a*d^3*b*x + a*d*b^2*x - 2*a*d^2*b^2*x - d^3*b^2*x + d*c*x + a*d*c*x + 
  a^2*d*c*x - 2*d^2*c*x - 2*a*d^2*c*x - 2*a^2*d^2*c*x - 3*a*d^3*c*x + 2*d*b*c*x + 2*a*d*b*c*x - 4*d^2*b*c*x - 
  4*a*d^2*b*c*x - 2*d^3*b*c*x - 2*a*d^3*b*c*x + d*b^2*c*x - 2*d^2*b^2*c*x - d^3*b^2*c*x + a*d*c^2*x - 
  2*a*d^2*c^2*x - d^3*c^2*x + d*b*c^2*x - 2*d^2*b*c^2*x - d^3*b*c^2*x - x^2 + 2*d*x^2 + 4*a*d^2*x^2 + 
  a^2*d^2*x^2 - a*b*x^2 + 2*a*d*b*x^2 + 3*d^2*b*x^2 + 2*a*d^2*b*x^2 + d^2*b^2*x^2 - a*c*x^2 + 2*a*d*c*x^2 + 
  3*d^2*c*x^2 + 2*a*d^2*c*x^2 - b*c*x^2 + 2*d*b*c*x^2 + 3*d^2*b*c*x^2 + d^2*c^2*x^2 - 2*d*x^3 - 2*a*d*x^3 - 
  2*d*b*x^3 - 2*d*c*x^3 + x^4
```

I tried using *Mathematica* to directly seek the minimum value, but it ran for a long time without any response.

```
Minimize[{f, 
  x - 1/2*(d*(2*a + b + c) + 
       Sqrt[d^2*(2*a + b + c)^2 + 8*a*(b + c)*(1 - 2*d)]) >= 0, 
  a >= b + 1, b >= c, b >= 1, c >= 0, d >= 0, d <= 1}, {x, a, b, c, 
  d}]
```

When I used **Lingo**, it only found a local minimum (3.6..) instead of the global minimum (even I choose the option Global Solve). I suspect that the objective expression may not have a global minimum within the given constraint range.

```
min=(-a^2)*d^2+2*a^2*d^3-a*d^2*b-a^2*d^2*b+2*a*d^3*b+2*a^2*d^3*b-a*d^2*b^2+2*a*d^3*b^2-a*d^2*c-
a^2*d^2*c+2*a*d^3*c+2*a^2*d^3*c+b*c-2*a*b*c+a^2*b*c-4*d*b*c+8*a*d*b*c-4*a^2*d*b*c+
4*d^2*b*c-12*a*d^2*b*c+4*a^2*d^2*b*c+8*a*d^3*b*c-d^2*b^2*c-a*d^2*b^2*c+2*d^3*b^2*c+
2*a*d^3*b^2*c-a*d^2*c^2+2*a*d^3*c^2-d^2*b*c^2-a*d^2*b*c^2+2*d^3*b*c^2+2*a*d^3*b*c^2-
d^2*b^2*c^2+2*d^3*b^2*c^2+2*a*d*x-4*a*d^2*x-2*a^2*d^3*x+d*b*x+a*d*b*x+a^2*d*b*x-2*d^2*b*x-
2*a*d^2*b*x-2*a^2*d^2*b*x-3*a*d^3*b*x+a*d*b^2*x-2*a*d^2*b^2*x-d^3*b^2*x+d*c*x+a*d*c*x+
a^2*d*c*x-2*d^2*c*x-2*a*d^2*c*x-2*a^2*d^2*c*x-3*a*d^3*c*x+2*d*b*c*x+2*a*d*b*c*x-4*d^2*b*c*x-
4*a*d^2*b*c*x-2*d^3*b*c*x-2*a*d^3*b*c*x+d*b^2*c*x-2*d^2*b^2*c*x-d^3*b^2*c*x+a*d*c^2*x-
2*a*d^2*c^2*x-d^3*c^2*x+d*b*c^2*x-2*d^2*b*c^2*x-d^3*b*c^2*x-x^2+2*d*x^2+4*a*d^2*x^2+
a^2*d^2*x^2-a*b*x^2+2*a*d*b*x^2+3*d^2*b*x^2+2*a*d^2*b*x^2+d^2*b^2*x^2-a*c*x^2+2*a*d*c*x^2+
3*d^2*c*x^2+2*a*d^2*c*x^2-b*c*x^2+2*d*b*c*x^2+3*d^2*b*c*x^2+d^2*c^2*x^2-2*d*x^3-2*a*d*x^3-
2*d*b*x^3-2*d*c*x^3+x^4;
x >= 1/2*(d*(2*a + b + c) + @SQRT((d)^2*(2*a + b + c)^2 + 8*a*(b + c)*(1 - 2*d))); 
a >= b + 1;
b >= c;
b >= 1;
c >= 0;
d >= 0;
d <= 1;
@GIN(a);
@GIN(b);
@GIN(c);
```

[image]

Can I use Mathematica in advance to observe whether the objective expression has a global minimum within the given constraint range? I suspect that my usage of Mathematica might be incorrect, or there might be better methods of proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment. I tried to do that with a new option `Method->"Couenne"` aimed on mixed-integer programming,

```
NMinimize[{f, 1/2 (-(2 a + b + c) d - 
Sqrt[8 a (b + c) (1 - 2 d) + (2 a + b + c)^2 d^2]) + x >= 0 &&
a >= 1 + b && b >= c && b >= 1 && c >= 0 && d >= 0 && 
d <= 1 && (a | b | c) \[Element] Integers}, {x, a, b, c, d}, Method -> "Couenne"]
```

,  but the above command is running without any response on my comp for hours.
It should be noticed that option is undocumented: I find only

> use the Couenne library for non-convex mixed-integer nonlinear problems

in [NMinimize/Details and Options](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html?q=NMinimize). The `Method->"Couenne"` option produces an incorrect result here with another objective function

```
NMinimize[{(-a^2)*d^2 + 2*a^2*d^3 - a*d^2*b - a^2*d^2,
 -1/2*(d*(2*a + b + c) +  Sqrt[d^2*(2*a + b + c)^2 + 8*a*(b + c)*(1 - 2*d)]) >= 0 && 
  a >= b + 1 && b >= c && b >= 1 && c >= 0 && d >= 0 && d <= 1 &&
 {a, b, c} \[Element] Integers}, {x, a, b, c, d},  Method -> "Couenne"]
```

> NMinimize::nsolc: There are no points that satisfy the constraints.`{\[Infinity], {x -> Indeterminate, a -> Indeterminate,  b -> Indeterminate, c -> Indeterminate, d -> Indeterminate}}`

in contradiction  with

```
FindInstance[{x-1/2*(d*(2*a+b+c)+Sqrt[d^2*(2*a+b+c)^2+
8*a*(b+c)*(1-2*d)])>=0,a>=b+1,b>=c,b>=1,c>=0,d>=0,d<=1,{a,b,c}\[Element]Integers},
{x,a,b,c,d},Reals,2]
```

> `{{x -> Root[-4 + 10*#1 - 8*#1^2 + #1^3 & , 1, 0], a -> 2, b -> 1,  c -> 0, d -> 1}, {x -> 2*(-1 + 2*Sqrt[2]), a -> 2, b -> 1, c -> 0,  d -> 89/221}}`

BTW, the [DirectSearch package](https://www.maplesoft.com/Applications/Detail.aspx?id=101333) of Maple produces

```
restart; Digits := 25:
DirectSearch:-GlobalOptima(f,{a>= b+1, b >= 1, b >= c, c >= 0, d >= 0, x-1/2*(d*(2*a+b+c)+
sqrt(d^2*(2*a+b+c)^2+8*a*(b+c)*(1-2*d))) >= 0, d <= 1}, tolerances = 10^(-13),
 evaluationlimit = 20000) assuming a::integer,b::integer,c::integer
```

> `[2.598288431856564111391720, [a = 2, b = 1, c = 1, d = .7991632770213002649244504, x = 3.377971884807877963717634], 854]`

which is better than the Lingo's result.

Comment: Good. Maybe you can see this link ([https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4706975/prove-an-inequality-or-find-the-global-optimum-solution?noredirect=1#comment9966969_4706975). I post the question to Math stack.  But I accept the Mathematica's solution.

Comment: @licheng: Sorry, you accepted the answer to another problem " after reducing the constraints" .

Comment: I cannot submit a bug to [WTS](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=Technical). I permanently see "Contact Us
Cannot reach server
There was a problem sending this message. Please try again later. You can also try to reach us by phone or chat (see contact information below).". I tried to submit a bug several times from different places.

Comment: I just tried that link and it appeared to go through.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Still cannot: "Свяжитесь с нами
Невозможно связаться с сервером
Возникла проблема с отправкой этого сообщения. Пожалуйста, повторите попытку позже. Вы также можете попытаться связаться с нами по телефону или в чате (см. контактную информацию ниже)".

Comment: Strange. I have case # 5054474.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Hope you have referred to this question.

Comment: I added a link to this thread to the case report.

Comment: @user64494, I encountered the same problem a few times. As far as I have managed to understand the cause, it was the presence of some special characters in the message (I think `<` and/or `>`). Try giving only "plain text" in the message box, and provide code in an attachment notebook.